# conditional formatting based on values from a column

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

I have a matrix in my google sheet. I want to color a cell if its value is present in another array, meaning one cell of that array is identical.
I am able to do it using conditional formatting and checking only one cell instead of the whole array, but this is not scalable to long  arrays.

Here is a practical example:

This is my matrix:

[image]

This is the array Z29:Z36

[image]

And this is the desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use Countif:

```
=countif($Z$29:$Z$36,D62)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use this custom formula on range **D62:V**:

```
=REGEXMATCH(D62, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, $Z$29:$Z$36))
```